# Google Calendar API - Get events sent from an Outlook account

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I am trying to access the events invitation I send from an external service like Outlook to a Google Account using the Google Calendar API.

It works well when I send a invitation from another google account, but not when it's coming from Outlook.

I thought the parameter "showHiddenInvitations=True" could help, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the sample of my code :

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'credentials.json'

def main():
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    try:
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Calendar API
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
        showHiddenInvitations = True
        events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', showHiddenInvitations= True).execute()
        events = events_result.get('items', [])

        if not events:
            print('No upcoming events found.')
            return

        # Prints the start and name of the events
        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            print(start, event['summary'])

    except HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you

Comment: Are those events from Outlook visible in Google Calendar?

Comment: As i am using a Service Account, I don't know... 
However, when I try to do it on a "normal" Google account, the events are in my calendar, even if I haven't accepted them yet

Maybe the behaviour on a service account is different ?

Comment: AFAIK some services do not support service accounts if you are not making impersonation of an actual user, see: [Authentication with service accounts](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts)